# Null pointer exception when spying on Activity with PowerMockito

Tags: java, android, testing, junit, powermockito

Good day, I am in the project phase of Google Africa Developer Scholarship for the Google Android Associate Developer path and as part of the project, we are provided with a project and all we are to do is write code that will make the tests to pass but anytime I try to run this any test that has to do with getting an activity I get this error, I tried searching around on anything regarding this on PowerMockito but I didn't find anything helpful.

I also tried using RoboElectric and Mockito to try to mock the activity but I'm still getting the same issue

The code

```
package com.pluralsight.candycoded;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@PrepareForTest({AppCompatActivity.class, MainActivity.class, Intent.class, InfoActivity.class})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class _1_StartTheStoreInformationActivity {

    private static boolean onOptionsItemSelected_result = true;
    private static boolean called_Intent = false;
    private static boolean called_Intent_correctly = false;
    private static boolean called_startActivity = false;

    // Mockito setup
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() throws Exception {
        // Spy on a MainActivity instance.
        MainActivity activity = PowerMockito.spy(new MainActivity());
        // Create a fake Bundle to pass in.
        Bundle bundle = Mockito.mock(Bundle.class);
        // Create a spy Intent to return from new Intent().
        Intent intent = PowerMockito.spy(new Intent(activity, InfoActivity.class));

        try {
            // Do not allow super.onCreate() to be called, as it throws errors before the user's code.
            PowerMockito.suppress(PowerMockito.methodsDeclaredIn(AppCompatActivity.class));

            // Return a mocked Intent from the call to its constructor.
            PowerMockito.whenNew(Intent.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(intent);

            // We expect calling onCreate() to throw an Exception due to our mocking. Ignore it.
            try {
                activity.onCreate(bundle);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                onOptionsItemSelected_result = activity.onOptionsItemSelected(null);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Check if new Intent() was called with any arguments.
            try {
                PowerMockito.verifyNew(Intent.class, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).withNoArguments();
                called_Intent = true;
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                PowerMockito.verifyNew(Intent.class, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).withArguments(Mockito.any(
                    MainActivity.class), Mockito.any(Class.class));
                called_Intent = true;
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Check if new Intent() was called with the correct arguments.
            PowerMockito.verifyNew(Intent.class, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).withArguments(Mockito.eq(activity), Mockito.eq(
                InfoActivity.class));
            called_Intent_correctly = true;

            // Check if startActivity() was called with the correct argument.
            Mockito.verify(activity).startActivity(Mockito.eq(intent));
            called_startActivity = true;

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void mainactivity_onoptionitemselected_return_super() throws Exception {
        override_mainactivity_onoptionitemselected();
        assertFalse("onOptionsItemSelected() does not return call to super.", onOptionsItemSelected_result);
    }

    @Test
    public void create_intent_infoactivity() throws Exception {
        override_mainactivity_onoptionitemselected();
        assertTrue("The Intent was not created.", called_Intent);
        assertTrue("The Intent was created but with the wrong parameters. @intent-infoactivity", called_Intent_correctly);
    }

    @Test
    public void startactivity_infoactivity() throws Exception {
        override_mainactivity_onoptionitemselected();
        assertTrue("The method startActivity() was not called.", called_startActivity);
    }

    @Test
    public void override_mainactivity_onoptionitemselected() throws Exception {
        // Determine if the method OnOptionsItemSelected() is implemented in MainActivity
        // or just in the Base class
        Class<?> myClass = null;

        try {
            myClass = MainActivity.class
                    .getMethod("onOptionsItemSelected", MenuItem.class)
                    .getDeclaringClass();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

        assertEquals("onOptionsItemSelected() method doesn't exist in MainActivity class.",
                myClass, MainActivity.class);

        assertEquals("onOptionsItemSelected() method doesn't exist in MainActivity class.",
                myClass, MainActivity.class);
    }
}
```

The exception I get when I try running the test and it tries to spy on MainActivity

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at androidx.arch.core.executor.DefaultTaskExecutor.isMainThread(DefaultTaskExecutor.java:77)
    at androidx.arch.core.executor.ArchTaskExecutor.isMainThread(ArchTaskExecutor.java:116)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.enforceMainThreadIfNeeded(LifecycleRegistry.java:316)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:172)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.<init>(ComponentActivity.java:244)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:103)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.<init>(AppCompatActivity.java:94)
    at com.pluralsight.candycoded.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:30)
    at com.pluralsight.candycoded._1_StartTheStoreInformationActivity.setup(_1_StartTheStoreInformationActivity.java:40)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runBefores(ClassRoadie.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:43)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:117)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:121)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

com.pluralsight.candycoded._1_StartTheStoreInformationActivity > classMethod FAILED
    java.lang.NullPointerException at _1_StartTheStoreInformationActivity.java:40
```

MainActivity

```
package com.pluralsight.candycoded;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.TextHttpResponseHandler;
import com.pluralsight.candycoded.DB.CandyContract;
import com.pluralsight.candycoded.DB.CandyCursorAdapter;
import com.pluralsight.candycoded.DB.CandyDbHelper;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private Candy[] candies;
  private final CandyDbHelper candyDbHelper = new CandyDbHelper(this);

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SQLiteDatabase db = candyDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM candy", null);

    final CandyCursorAdapter adapter = new CandyCursorAdapter(this, cursor);
    ListView listView = this.findViewById(R.id.list_view_candy);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, i, l) -> {
      Intent detailIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
      detailIntent.putExtra("position", i);
      startActivity(detailIntent);
    });

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("https://vast-brushlands-23089.herokuapp.com/main/api",
        new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
          @Override
          public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String response, Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e("AsyncHttpClient", "response = " + response);
          }

          @Override
          public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String response) {
            Log.d("AsyncHttpClient", "response = " + response);
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            candies = gson.fromJson(response, Candy[].class);

            addCandiesToDatabase(candies);

            SQLiteDatabase db = candyDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM candy", null);
            //adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
          }
        });
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  // ***
  // Task 1 - Show Store Information Activity
  // ***
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, InfoActivity.class));
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  private void addCandiesToDatabase(Candy[] candies) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = candyDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    for (Candy candy : candies) {
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(CandyContract.CandyEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NAME, candy.name);
      values.put(CandyContract.CandyEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PRICE, candy.price);
      values.put(CandyContract.CandyEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DESC, candy.description);
      values.put(CandyContract.CandyEntry.COLUMN_NAME_IMAGE, candy.image);

      db.insert(CandyContract.CandyEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
  }
}
```

Please anyone know what is wrong?